# SwiftUI Toggle Switch without Binding

Tags: swiftui, binding, toggle

This may seem like an odd question but I have looked around and can't seem to find an answer for it.

I would like to create toggles in a view that are not binded to any variable. Imagine a list of toggle switches that are toggle-able  but don't actually do anything.

I have tried using .constant butt as you would expect, that doesn't allow me to toggle the switch. Obviously leaving It blank throws an error.

```
//Can't be changed
Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) {
       Text("Checkbox")
}

//Throws an error
Toggle() {
       Text("Checkbox")
}
```

Is there anything that can be passed in the isOn: parameter to allow for that?

Edit:

In theory I could just have a @State variable in my view and binding to the toggle and simple not used that variable anywhere else in my view. Only thing is, I do not know ahead of time how many toggles will be displayed in my view so I can't just declare a bunch of @State variables. And if I were too only create one @State variable and blind it to all of my toggles, they would all be in sync, which is not what I am looking for, I would like them to all be independent.

Below is a simplified example of the layout of my view

```
private var array: [String]
var body: some View {
    ForEach((0..<self.array.count), id: \.self) {
        Toggle("Show welcome message", isOn: *binding here*)
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You will just have to have `@State` variables in the view.

Comment: Thank you but maybe I did not explained my goal fully. If I'm not mistaken, having @State variables would require me to know how much I need. In my case, the number of toggles on screen is variable and I do not know ahead of time how many there will be. thank you

Comment: If you add some more code which maybe demonstrates some stack or grid of `Toggle`s, I can provide an answer. You can just use a single `@State` of type `[Bool]`. This means that each one can be controlled individually and it can be any amount.

Comment: Uhh what is this for? If it's prototyping maybe `Toggle(isOn: .constant(Bool.random()), label: {`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a single `@State` variable of type `[Bool]`, an array containing all the toggle booleans.

Here is some example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ToggleStack(count: 5)
    }
}

struct ToggleStack: View {
    @State private var toggles: [Bool]
    private let count: Int
    
    init(count: Int) {
        self.count = count
        toggles = Array(repeating: true, count: count)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< count) { index in
                Toggle(isOn: $toggles[index]) {
                    Text("Checkbox")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick, I never though of declaring an array of Bools, very appreciated!